# The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256

Tags: java, jwt

I have created a JWT validation method, it was working in some systems except one. Now I am getting this message:

> The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256

See my code:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("Abcd");            
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();            
verifier.verify(auth);
```

My token is:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFiY2QiLCJoYXNoIjoiYWFhYUAxMjMifQ.itPMz9wALbF4w5QiQ7F5MikI3gKjTFwIwq8ldhcz99o

Do you have any solution?

Comment: with com.auth0.java-jwt-3.3.0 the token seems to be correct. what version are you using?

Comment: @pero_hero <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
it was working .. but now i had a new system it is not

Comment: I guess the code should run on any system. how do you generate the jwt?